# What do special unitary groups $SU(n)$ represent geometrically?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, mathematics, lie-algebra, linear-algebra

It's frequently said that special orthogonal group $SO(n)$ represent rotations in $n$-dimensional space. What do $SU(n)$ groups represent?

Comment: How is this not a [math.se] question?

Comment: What math represents seems somewhat opinion-based. I think of $SU(n)$ as “rotations” in an $n$-dimensional space whose coordinates are complex rather than real. The rotations preserve the natural generalization of “length” in this space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$SO(n)$ transformations preserve the length of a *real* vector in $n$-dimensional space: $\vec v'=R(\Omega)\vec v$ with $\vec v'\cdot \vec v'=\vec v
\cdot v$.

$SU(n)$ transformations preserve the length of a *complex* vector in $n$-dimensional space: $\vert v'\rangle= U(\Omega) \vert v\rangle$ with
$ \langle v'\vert v'\rangle= \langle v\vert v\rangle$.

As quantum mechanics deals with *complex* vectors, unitary transformation also preserve inner products and thus probability amplitudes:
$\langle w'\vert v'\rangle=\langle w\vert v\rangle$.

In both cases, the $S$ of $SO(n)$ or $SU(n)$ specifies that the determinant of the transformation is $+1$.  $O(n)$ for instance include reflections, which have determinant $-1$, while $U(n)$ have determinant of the from $e^{i\varphi}$, *i.e.* a phase.

Comment: Good answer, but it should also address the "special" part of both groups.

Comment: @J.G. good point.  Fixed.